# Read file and print numbers not in the file

Tags: c

So i'm fairly new to C (I am using the C language) and i want to print a list of numbers between 1 and 90 inclusive. BUT i only want to print the list of numbers that are not in a specified file called reserved.txt (which should only store a list of int numbers). On the first run of the program (when reserved is null, the user is asked to enter a number between 1 and 90 inclusive. This number is then stored in reserved.txt. When reserved does contain AT LEAST 1 number however I want to print all numbers between 1 and 90 inclusive to the screen except for the any numbers stored in reserved.txt. So i basically want to jump over or ignore the values in reserved.txt when printing the values to the screen. Any suggestions? Doesn't have to be very detailed. 
NB. The file is arranged in ascending order each time after the first run, if that helps.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?  If you didn't start at all: Try solving parts of the problem: Printing the numbers from 1 to 90, reading integers from a file, …  If all individual parts work in isolation, combine them to your final solution.

Comment: One way you could do it, would be to first read in the reserved.txt into an array of integers.  Then, have an outer loop that loops from 1 to 90, and each pass check the array for that value.  If the number in reserved array is > than the current pass, you can print all the way to there without checking the array.

Comment: Try it in the shell: `seq 1 90 | grep -v -f reserved.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try an array like this:

```
unsigned int reserved_integers[max_value];
```

Then use a function to fill it in.

```
void fill_table() {
  FILE *input = fopen( "reserved.txt", "r" );
  if (input == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int x = 0;
  char word[5];
  for (; i < max_value; i++) {
    if(fgets( word, 5, input ) == NULL) break;
    x = atoi( word );
    reserved_integers[x] = i;
  }
}
```

Finally, loop through printing the value of array indexes that are equal to zero (I'll let you figure it out yourself).

Comment: fgets returns the string, so eof returns the empty string.

Comment: `fgets()` does _not_ do anything to `x`  on End-of-file.  "If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged ..." C11 §7.21.7.2

Comment: @chux Sorry, that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: On `EOF`, `fgets()` returns a `char *` with the value `NULL`.  It does not return an empty string on `EOF`.  Certainly code generates a warning/error with `check = fgets( word, 5, input );`.   Consider `if (fgets( word, sizeof word, input ) == NULL) break; `  No need for `if (strcmp(check, "") == 0) break;`